# Is there any way to link to a Google Presentation and if using iOS have it open in Google Drive app?

Tags: google-drive, google-classic-sites, ios

We have some sites that want link to various presentation's, idealy our staff should click on a link and be able to present it.

We have linked to the presentation but it opens in the mobile web view. we'd like it to open in the Google Drive app.